# Proxy setting for HttpClient 4 not working

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient, proxy-authentication, http-status-code-407

I am using Apache HttpClient library to connect to url. The network in which i am doing has a secure proxy to it. when i am using the java.net package to connect to the url i just have to add the

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxy);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
```

no proxy userid and password is needed to be passed but when i am trying to connect through  httpclient i am getting 407 **proxy authentication error**.My code is:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("xyz.abc.com",8080,"http");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
```

Proxy is using NTML authentication.I don't want to pass userid and password.

Comment: The nearest answer i find is on stackoverflow :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962047/apache-httpclient-4-1-proxy-authentication

I just think that NTLM credentials of your windows system are not accessible from your java layer and then you need to reauthenticate to the proxy. I might be wrong.

Comment: First of all i think the out of box NTML support is not there in HttpClient,Secondly the credential changes quite frequently so i can't use in that way. accessing credentials of my windows system through java layer if it available to java.net package URLConnect so it would be available for httpclient library also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded to **httpclient 4.2** and this version has out of box NTML support. Just need to add following lines to the code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials("user", "pwd", "myworkstation", "microsoft.com");
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
```

For further reading Httpclent authentication scheme u can refer http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#d5e947

But my question is still open, why HttpClent is not picking the system proxy as simple java program does.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the system properties to be picked up, you could use [SystemDefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultHttpClient.html) instead of DefaultHttpClient.

As of HttpClient 4.3, this class has been deprecated in favor of [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html):

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClientBuilder().useSystemProperties().build();
```