# How to parse JSON dat with HTTP Post method in android studio

Tags: android, json, parsing

JSONParser.class

```
package com.example.diptiagravat.myapplication;

public class JSONParser {

    public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String sendHTTPData(String urlpath, String id) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url=new URL(urlpath);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            streamWriter.write(id);
            streamWriter.flush();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String response = null;
                while ((response = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(response + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

                Log.d("test", stringBuilder.toString());
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } else {
                Log.e("test", connection.getResponseMessage());
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e("test", exception.toString());
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.diptiagravat.myapplication;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtid, txtcname;
    Spinner spcnt, spstate;
    public ArrayList<String> clist;
    ArrayAdapter<String> cad;
    public ArrayList<String> slist;
    ArrayAdapter<String> sad;
    public String strcnt;
    private static String url = "http://urmiinfotech.com/demo/ifirst/app_api/get_country_list.php";
    private static String stateUrl = "http://urmiinfotech.com/demo/ifirst/app_api/get_state_list.php";
    private static final String TAG_USER = "country";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "country_name";
    private ArrayList<Country> clistModels;

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();

        CountryAsyncTask countryAsyncTask= new CountryAsyncTask();
        countryAsyncTask.execute();
    }

    private void initViews() {

        txtid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvid);
        txtcname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcname);
        spcnt = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spcnt);
        spstate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spstate);
        clist = new ArrayList<String>();
        slist = new ArrayList<String>();

    }


    public class CountryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jParser.getJSON(url, 5000));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return json.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.i("Result Ravi", result);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray cntArray = obj.getJSONArray("country");

                if (cntArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cntArray.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject temp = cntArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //  txtid.setText(temp.getString("id"));
                        //  txtcname.setText(temp.getString("country_name"));


                        Country country = new Gson().fromJson(temp.toString(), Country.class);
                        clist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        clistModels = new ArrayList<Country>();
                        clistModels.add(new Country(temp.optString("id"), temp.optString("country_name"), "", null));
                        clist.add(temp.getString("country_name"));
                        cad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, clist);
                        spcnt.setAdapter(cad);
                        spcnt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                strcnt = clistModels.get(position).getId();
                                //strcnt = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                Log.i("id", strcnt);
                                new StatesAsyncTask().execute();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                        // txtid.setText(temp.getString(country.getId()));
                        // txtcname.setText(temp.getString(country.getCountryName()));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class StatesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL


            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jParser.sendHTTPData(stateUrl, strcnt));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             return json.toString();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray stArray = obj.getJSONArray("statelist");

                if (stArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < stArray.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject temp = stArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //  txtid.setText(temp.getString("id"));
                        //  txtcname.setText(temp.getString("country_name"));


                        Statelist stlist = new Gson().fromJson(temp.toString(), Statelist.class);
                        slist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        // clistModels = new ArrayList<Country>();
                        //clistModels.add(new Country(temp.optString("id"), temp.optString("country_name"), "", null));
                        slist.add(temp.getString("state_name"));
                        sad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, slist);
                        spstate.setAdapter(sad);
                        spstate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                // strcnt = clistModels.get(position).getId();
                                //strcnt = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                // Log.i("id", strcnt);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                        // txtid.setText(temp.getString(country.getId()));
                        // txtcname.setText(temp.getString(country.getCountryName()));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

My response is null?

Comment: This will be helpfull http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm or http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks but i already seen this tutorial.in my JSONParser class response variable is null. i cant get data.

Comment: What is the status code from the server

Comment: Three have no problem in getJson method but problem arise in sendHttpData method i cant get response in stringBuilder object

Comment: Trying Volley and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpURLConnection` is deprecated in Android Lollipop, so please try to use `DefaultHttpClient` instead. Also, check your logs, this is at your `onPostExecute()`:

```
Log.i("Result Ravi", result);
```

For `DefaultHttpClient` check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374156/sending-and-parsing-response-using-http-client-for-a-json-list).

Another way is to try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Yes i got the json in Log, but When i passed sendHttpData in Json i get json=null.

Comment: in this url http://urmiinfotech.com/demo/ifirst/app_api/get_state_list.php you got json null ,so please check pasing parameter and  fire this url in browser   with proper  parameter

Comment: I found the solution using volley. Thanks to all