# Apache HttClient with Proxy not working in the Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, httpclient

I have a web application, made using Jsf and Apache HttpClient. When trying to consume an Api that requires a Proxy for communication, if I run the code via the command line on the server it works, but if I run the same code via a web application through Tomcat I get the "Name or service not known" error.

Java versão 11
Apache HttpClient 4.5.14

```
private String getCpf(String tokenClient) throws IOException {
    String result = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Inicio do processamento.....");
        
        System.out.println("Token informado: " + tokenClient);
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        
        System.out.println("Configurando o proxy...");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("111.111.111.111", 8080);
        DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
        //HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "https://servidor.com.br/api-servidor/api/login/validatoken");

        httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenClient.replace("\"", ""));

        httpGet.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
        
        System.out.println("Antes do envio....");
        
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        System.out.println("Apos o envio....");
    
        System.out.println("Coletando o retorno....");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("Código do retorno: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        if (entity != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println("Retorno em string: " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println("Convertendo o retorno em json....");
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(result);
            
            result = jsonNode.get("cpfcnpj").asText();
            System.out.println("Cpf retornado: " + result);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        return result;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Fim da execução....");
    return result;
}
```

I've already tried setting the proxy through environment variables and through Tomcat's setenv.xml too, but it only works if I run it outside of Tomcat.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358838/936329

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but the implementation is working, what is not working is when the Api is consumed via the Tomcat call.
Note. The proxy in question is the type without authentication.